# Copy sensor_msgs::LaserScanPtr& from callback function

Tags: ros, laser, shared-ptr

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a local class member that I have defined as follows

> sensor_msgs::LaserScan *current_scan_
> = new sensor_msgs::LaserScan;

I also have a callback function which is called when a new laser scan is available on a /scan topic:

> void
> CallbackHandler::getCurLaserScan(const
> sensor_msgs::LaserScanConstPtr&
> laser_in)

The question is, how can I assign a LaserScanConstPtr& object to a LaserScan* object? Is this assignment even possible?
What is the advised way in manipulating incoming laser scans from the function?

The purpose of this, is to have a LaserScan object on the heap with the most recent laser scan contents.

Thanks in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231837/copy-sensor_msgs::laserscanptr&-from-callback-function/) by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 257 on 2016-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What does `*current_scan = *laser_in` do?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on 2016-04-13**:
My goal is to make the current LaserScan, given at the getLaserScan callback, available outside the scope of the callback function. So I thought I could assign the contents of  laser_in to a pointer in the heap, and then refer to the current laser scan by dereferencing the pointer each time I need..

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-04-14**:
@dornhege: Shouldn't that be `*current_scan = *laser_in;` ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-04-14**:
Thanks @Felix Endres , Corrected.

**Comment by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on 2016-04-14**:
As it turns out that's one way to do it, yes..
In my situation, given that the callback function is inside a class, i Initialised a sensor_msgs::LaserScan variable on the stack and assigned the contents of laser_in inside the callback function.